# SharePoint 2010 Infopath Rule to hide section based on initiator

Tags: 2010, infopath, infopath-rules

Creating a form in infopath 2010, I want to create a rule that hides a section of fields based on if the **initiator** equals a manager field value. Is there a way to set up a rule depending on who sends the form after filling it out in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Add your group of fields as a section to the form. And then insert a Formatting rule on the section to "Hide" the control based on your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule to check if 'createdBy' and 'Manager' fields are same. If they are the same, apply formatting rules to hide the section

Comment: My form has a field for 'Manager' but does not have a field for createdBy. Is there a way to do this if my form does not have a createdBy field?

Comment: You can create a data connection to the forms library to get the created by field. Please refer this http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2011/05/display-who-last-modified-infopath-form-sharepoint-form-library/. If you do not want to show the created by field on the form, you can hide that field.